# How to listen to events in flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to close the webview in my flutter app when the user clicks on a button which is present in the webview

Here is the code which displays the webview

```
class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewAppState createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  WebviewScaffold(url: 'https://google.com',
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: kBlue,
          leading: BackButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Router.navigator.pop();
            },
          )
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

[image: example image and i want to detect if the sports]

Comment: Show the url which you are using for webview, and which button you want to be pressed inside your webview to close it?

Comment: Lets say i want to detect if the user clicked on sports.

Answer (score 18):

Please check the below steps for getting a trigger when the button in a WebView is clicked:

- Add  [webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

  > `webview_flutter: ^3.0.4`
- Added the reference of asset in the `pubspec.yaml`

  > ```
  >  assets:   
  >     assets/about_us.html
  > ```
- Added the html file in the assets folder

> **about_us.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function invokeNative() {
            MessageInvoker.postMessage('Trigger from Javascript code');
        }
    </script> </head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="invokeNative()" />
    </form> </body>

</html>
```

- Added the code for loading WebView.

> As per the below statement, you can see I am loading a WebView and
> when I click on the button named *Click me!* in WebView the
> JavascriptChannel in flutter will get invoked with a message "Trigger
> from Javascript code"
>
> ```
> import 'dart:convert';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
> import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 
> import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
>
> class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
>   WebViewApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
>   final String title;
>   @override
>   _WebViewAppState createState() => _WebViewAppState();
> }
>
> class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
>   WebViewController _controller;
>   Future<void> loadHtmlFromAssets(String filename, controller) async {
>     String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString(filename);
>     controller.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
>             mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
>         .toString());
>   }
>   Future<String> loadLocal() async {
>     return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/about_us.html');
>   }
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: Text(widget.title),
>       ),
>       body: FutureBuilder<String>(
>         future: loadLocal(),
>         builder: (context, snapshot) {
>           if (snapshot.hasData) {
>             return WebView(
>               initialUrl:
>                   new Uri.dataFromString(snapshot.data, mimeType: 'text/html')
>                       .toString(),
>               javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
>               javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
>                 JavascriptChannel(
>                     name: 'MessageInvoker',
>                     onMessageReceived: (s) {
>                     Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
>                        content: Text(s.message),
>                     ));
>                     }),
>               ].toSet(),
>             );
>           } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
>             return Text("${snapshot.error}");
>           }
>           return CircularProgressIndicator();
>         },
>       ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

As you can see in the code there is a `JavascriptChannel` which will get invoked when the user clicks a button in webview. There is a key to identify the channel which in my case was `MessageInvoker`.

Hopes this will do the trick...
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. This question technically answers the question. But my intention was to listen to any event on any website and not only the html i add .

Comment: As far as I know, jschannel/jsinterface is the only option available to enable the communication b/w JavaScript code and client-side flutter code.

Comment: thanks for this great example
but when I try this, it works fine in debug mode, but in production it is not working.
Any idea?

Comment: @FirasNizam It should not be dependent on build type. Are you loading same webpage in prod &debug?

Answer (score 10):

You can listen to the clicks by checking the url `WebView` is about to open:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
  navigationDelegate: (request) {
    if (request.url.contains('mail.google.com')) {
      print('Trying to open Gmail');
      Navigator.pop(context); // Close current window
      return NavigationDecision.prevent; // Prevent opening url
    } else if (request.url.contains('youtube.com')) {
      print('Trying to open Youtube');
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; // Allow opening url
    } else {
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; // Default decision
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **navigationDelegate** parameter in Webview constroctor.

```js
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
  navigationDelegate: (action) {
    if (action.url.contains('google.com')) {
      // Won't redirect url
      print('Trying to open google');
      Navigator.pop(context); 
      return NavigationDecision.prevent; 
    } else if (action.url.contains('youtube.com')) {
     // Allow opening url
      print('Trying to open Youtube');
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; 
    } else {
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; 
    }
  },
),
```

That's it!